# Centering a block of Bootstrap cols with a short item at the end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a block of Bootstrap like so:

```
<div class='my_row'>
   <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>Something long</div>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>Something else</div>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>Hi</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and some css:

```
.my_row {
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Assuming I've written the css properly (made up on the fly), this will technically work: I'll get a row of 3 items, properly centered on the page.  But, even though the outermost div is centered, the small amount of stuff in the rightmost col-sm-4 makes the overall content look like it's somewhat over to the left. (And I don't always know at coding time how much text will be in the different divs, so I can't cheat and set the last div to a col-sm-2 or some such.)

What would be nice would be if I could get the col-sm-4's to act like col-sm-4's regarding layout, but automatically adjust their size down to the size of their content, and then feed that back up to the .row, so that I'd get a closer approximation to visual centeredness.  Is this possible?  I could probably break out of Bootstrap and hand-coded it all, but I'm prefer to hold onto Bootstrap for all the other obvious reasons.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 4, you could use something like this without any custom css:

```
<div class='my_row'>
   <div class='row justify-content-center'>
      <div class='col-auto'>Something long</div>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>Something else</div> <!-- The column whose content will most likely fit into this size. Not necessarily in the center. -->
      <div class='col-auto'>Hi</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This way, all rows will take up only as much space as they need and still be centralized.

The key here is to give only one of the columns a predefined size limit. In my case the center element (so that the left and right element can get the chance to grow as much as possible.).

Where this solution is nice is that is nicely wraps the last last line and still centralizes it along with others if ever it gets too big to fit on the same line.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it might be time to upgrade to Bootstrap 4... :)